How can I distribute an exam to a large class without a lockdown broswer such as Respondus/Proctorio?
I teach math in a small college with small endowment; we do not have lots of budget to go around. When giving a test to a large class, ideally one should print out the problem sheets ahead of time and distribute them to student individually during test time. But the copy machine in my department is best described as rickety and unreliable.
In other campuses, I used to use lockdown browser Respondus or Proctorio for the tests, especially in short Summer semesters. But we do not have this luxury in my current campus.  The LMS we have, BrightSpace by D2L, does not come with lockdown browser enhancement.
Is there any alternative method to using lockdown browser?
Thank you for your time.

How large does "a large class" mean in this context?

Respondus and Proctorio are not so much "locked down browsers" as they are "abusive spyware". I hope you find an alternative.

@preferred_anon: It's not abusive if it's running on hardware owned by the school and the students are clearly warned that their activities on said hardware may be pervasively monitored.

To Jochen Glueck - About 30 students each section, generally two sections per semester.

@Kevin I disagree; the school should be forbidden from making such an agreement a condition of taking the exam.

@preferred_anon: This will, to some extent, be a matter of local laws and privacy regulations. But at least in some countries, you very much can make such an agreement mandatory, because the student always has the option of using their personal device for all personal browsing, and is clearly warned of the consequences if they choose to do anything personal on the school device.

@preferred_anon: That's a legitimate critique of something like webcams monitoring work at home. But it's a pretty dumb thing to say about in-class tests on school hardware (and the software OP references doesn't even have that capability). Do you not let in-person proctors watch the room for prohibited devices when students take tests?

@DanielR.Collins No need to resort to name calling :-) Being watched by a person is just not the same as being watched by a machine. Humans do not generally record everything that is seen, do not generalise observe everything that is visible, and can be reasoned with in the case of mistakes. I am sure if a proctor was sat next to you, watching your every motion, and writing everything in a book that was sent of with the exam paper, that you would not consider it so obviously harmless.

@preferred_anon: Respondus does not do that ("record everything that is seen"). You've confused this with some other tool.

@DanielR.Collins Respondus and Proctorio both can and do do that, but apparently the locked-down browser is a separable piece of software that need not come with the other (imo abusive) features. I didn't understand that previously (and if that's what you meant, why didn't you just say so?)

@preferred_anon: I did, see comment above ("the software OP references doesn't even have that capability"). Citation would be needed that "both can and do do that", I don't see that anywhere.

@DanielR.Collins Proctorio calls this "Online Proctoring" and Respondus calls it "Respondus Monitor". Both companies are famous for these tools, since they had widespread use during the COVID lockdowns. If you were referring to the locked-down browser all along, then I don't understand your original comment ("do you not let in-person proctors watch the room") - which seems to directly refer to surveillance, and not merely disabling the capabilities of a computer.

@preferred_anon: The title of the question is "LockDown Browser", not "Monitor". Read carefully.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The simplest solution would be to go to a local copy shop, office supply store, or pack-and-ship store and have them print the exam papers for you.  Photocopies are generally a few cents per page, and printing from a digital file can sometimes be even cheaper (especially if you don't need them the same day, or supply your own paper).  I know it's an extra expense, but it's not much and it's usually worth it when you consider the cost of the time, resources, and sheer hassle involved with trying to implement some sort of electronic solution.  Your department may even reimburse you for the cost if it was due to a failure of the equipment provided.
I once had an instructor who asked every student to bring $2 on the first day of class to cover printing expenses.  Only about half the class actually did it, but it was enough to cover his expenses for the entire course.  On exam day, he'd hand everyone a printed exam plus several sheets of blank paper for scratch work and recording answers.  Writing answers on separate paper meant the exam could typically be consolidated down to a single page, plus we were instructed not to write on the exam so he likely re-used the papers with the afternoon class.

That is also feasible. Thank you for your input!

I once faced a similar issue.
My classes were in-person and not very big, so the following solution was sufficient for me:

email a PDF of the exam to the students

tell them that the PDF is the only screen they are allowed to have open (and also put that in writing at the top of the PDF)

sit at the back of the classroom, every student's screen in plain sight, while they take the exam


Of course I was mostly doing other stuff, not staring at their screens the whole time, but it wasn't too much trouble to glance up every so often to do a spot-check.

Maybe put it on the blackboard?

Low tech!  What a concept.  See https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/12945/229

Thanks for the response. But sometimes it is not entirely possible because some problems are long and drown-out, involving graph, etc. Thank you again though.

@A.Magnus Not to mention the fact that not everyone will have the same level of access to whatever is written on a blackboard / whiteboard at the front of the room (e.g. it is going to be easier for someone up front to see what is going on than someone in the back).  And students are likely to feel somewhat aggrieved by the perceived cheapness of the method---they've paid good money to take that class, basic supplies should be provided (e.g. exam sheets).

@XanderHenderson the accessibility argument is good, but the "perceived cheapness" is not particularly compelling.  Yes, they can be given paper - maybe A. Magnus has bluebooks available? - but for certain types of exams and rooms this would be a very feasible solution, and one students maybe prefer to LockDown Browser.  An accommodation for partly visually impaired students, if there are few, would be easy to provide (namely, one written piece of paper).  Actually pdfs are worse from this standpoint for math stuff, most mathematical ones are not usable by screenreaders (or so I am told).

@kcrisman I mentioned "perceived cheapness" only because that is an actual thing which was commented upon in a class I TA'd for while in grad school.  In a 30 person class, 8 people complained about the instructor not handing out paper exams, and writing problems on the board.  Several of them asked how hard it would be to just print out the damn problems.  So you may not find it compelling, but my experience tells me that students want to be handed paper exams (when it is possible to do so).

@XanderHenderson I'm truly sorry to hear that :-( perhaps a reality check was in order for some of those students.  And to be fair, in a place with a graduate program, probably it would NOT be hard to just print them out!  Perhaps at the OP's institution students would be more accommodating (even though this doesn't work for that specific exam), particularly if honest about wanting to guarantee that a busy/unreliable copier didn't mean the exam started late.  Experience definitely teaches that starting an exam late is sure to cause complaints :-)

@kcrisman Indeed---the crappy copier is the real problem here.  If I were in that position, I would probably just bite the bullet and spend $200 of my own money on a cheap laserjet.  Such a tool is more than sufficient for the typical class sizes at a SPLAC.

Paper Exams
I would strongly recommend that you find a way to ensure that students have paper exams.  In my opinion, this is the best case for the vast majority of students.
If your institution / department cannot afford a printer / copier which reliably works, it might be well worth it to spend your own money to buy a cheap laserjet printer.[1]  Alternatively, if you are in a large enough populated area, there should be some business which can make copies for you (Kinko's, OfficeMax, some local mom-and-pop, etc).[2]
You could save some of the printing costs by printing out only the questions without space to write answers, then have students write their answers on blank sheets of paper (which you can provide).  This isn't my favorite approach, as I use the space on the exam to sort of hint about how long a typical answer should be, but not everyone does this, so it might be fine.
Or you could just put the exam questions on your LMS (visible only during the exam), tell students to access the LMS during the exam period (using whatever device they have access to), and not worry so much about cheating (by which I mean "do the normal things you would do to monitor your testing environment, but don't kill yourself).[3]
Putting Questions on the Board
As suggested by another answer, you could write the questions on the whiteboard / blackboard.  Or type up the questions and project them onto a screen.
This is a viable option, though I think that it creates some problems with respect to accessibility, in that not everyone is going to have the same view of the board / screen.  Moreover, if you are writing things on the board, your handwriting had better be immaculate.
Lockdown Browsers / Locked Down Computers
I have a great dislike for lockdown browsers.  In order for a lockdown browser to do its job, it essentially needs to "root" the machine on which it is installed (the browser needs low-level access to the machine).  This opens up all kinds of holes for other malware to get in, and I'm not even sure that I trust the browser publishers.  These things just feel icky to me.
I avoid such tools as much as possible.[4]
On the other hand, if you are giving your exam in a computer lab, or if the machines being used are otherwise owned by your institution, it should be possible to place the exam on each machine (e.g. as a .pdf) and turn off all network access.  You might talk to your IT department about how this could work (it is not an entirely trivial thing to do, but definitely possible).
Use Another Form of Assessment

I've had a lot of luck in the past with oral exams: I give students a list of five problems about a week before the exam date, and they have that time to prepare solutions.  During finals week, each student makes a 20 minute appointment for the examination.  At the start of the exam, a student may opt to:

remove one question from the list---I then roll a four sided die, and they answer whichever question corresponds to that roll; or

double up on a question from the list---I roll a six sided die, and they answer whichever question corresponds to that roll (on a six, they answer the question they doubled up on).


While they work through their solution, I ask lots of questions to see where they have difficulty.  The downsides of this approach are that questions have to be well written (so that they potentially cover a large swathe of the material covered during a semester, and are open ended enough to invite questions during the oral examination) and it doesn't scale very well (I can't imagine giving this option to more than 100 students in a semester).

Have students end the semester with some kind of presentation.  While I have not actually done this in the past, I think that it would be reasonable to give students a list of "difficult" problems / topics to choose from, then allow them to work in groups to solve those problems (or research that topic) and then present their findings to the rest of the class.  In general, I think that it is not too hard to tell whether or not students understand the material well, and whether or not all of the students in a group of two or three have made real contributions.

Give some kind of take home "exam" where the questions might require some amount of research effort.  If you know that your students are going to be using the internet, why not lean into it?  Again, this requires a great deal of effort to craft the problems / research topics you are giving to your students, but this also has the potential to be a much more authentic form of assessment.



[1] I had a decent HP printer for about 15 years; when it died, I replaced it with a Brother printer---neither cost more than $300 new, and both could print off hundreds of pages fairly quickly.
[2] Contrary to one of the other answers to this question, I would not ask students to give you cash for this.  Asking students for money leaves a bad taste in my mouth---while it may not be unethical, strictly speaking, it has serious feel-bads.  Copies should not be so expensive as to justify those feel-bads.
[3] My experience is that students are bad at cheating.  As an example, I teach a lot of asynchronous classes.  All exams, other than the final, are taken in settings where I have no control at all over the testing environment---I assume that students are cheating like crazy.  However, the ways in which they cheat are typically quite obvious---for example, a student giving me a decimal expansion out to 12 places has obviously used a calculator (which is typically against the rules); a student referencing kinematic equations in a Calc I class has obviously spent some time on Wikipedia (or similar).  The students who feel the need to cheat typically lack the skills to cheat well.
Moreover, students only cheat because they think that (a) the assessment is so important that they must pass, and (b) they don't know the material well enough to do well.  Lowering the stakes of individual assessments does a lot more to reduce cheating than anything else I've tried.  To lower the stakes, try more, smaller assessments; more take home work; more work which can be done collaboratively; more opportunities for revision; and so on.
[4]  I feel slightly different about the idea of a lockdown browser if the computers being used are owned and administered by your institution, but they still feel kind of icky to me.  My preference is to find another way.

Thank you for your extra long response. I will surely look at them seriously. Best regards from me.

The D2L Brightspace platform does have access to the Respondus LockDown Browser built in by default. (My school switched to D2L recently and I have it available in each course page under Quizzes > LockDown Browser.) See the D2L knowledge base page for more information.
If you don't see access to it right now, contact your system administrators, as they do need to configure it in advance, per that help page (in particular, someone needs to go into Admin Tools and click the Respondus v4.0 checkbox; note at the very bottom of the help page what it looks like to the instructor when it's turned on).

No, very unfortunately my school's license does not include the lock-down enhancement. This was confirmed by the admin person.  Thank you though for your input.

@A.Magnus: I fear your IT may be giving you incorrect information; the D2L site doesn't say anything about it being an add-on license. It does say the local admin has to configure it, which maybe they don't want to do.

Ok, l will forward this message to the Admin person.

If you have admin rights, you don't need a lockdown browser for this. You can block the global internet on Windows (or Linux, but I presume you use Windows) via firewall rules.
Search for "block all sites except one", this is a common practice. Here is one video. Leave only the LMS accessible. Here is the option with Tinywall or older Windows firewall.
Then, give students a limited parental-control account for test-taking, where everything that could be used to cheat is blocked.
A very small proportion of students will be able to bypass the blocks, but you probably shouldn't worry about their test scores, as it takes pretty good CS skills.
Ideally, you'd ask your systems administrator to do this via group policies, it's an easy task for any full-time admin, commonly done in organizations.

This assumes that the instructor has administrator/ root access to all of the machines being used for testing. This send like an unreasonable assumption in many / most cases.

Thank you. Let me look at its possibility.

@XanderHenderson True, ideally this is something you'd have the sysadmin do.

@Therac Often, students are bringing their own machines.  It simply isn't realistic to expect all of them to put those machines into a "safe" or "locked down" status.  It just isn't practical.  I also really don't feel like it is worth it.  There is a Duning-Krueger effect in play here:  those students who don't know the material also generally lack the skills to cheat effectively.  I tend to prefer to tone down the stress level during exams---if students are less stressed out about how important an exam is, they are less likely to attempt to cheat.

@XanderHenderson Just how broke can a college in the US be? I've been in a lot of third-world countries, and except for a few LDCs that lack consistent electric supply, there's always been at least enough desktop computers to host tests for a class.

Why do you assume that cost is the issue?  My institution has many laptops which students can check out from the library to use, but most students would rather use their own, so we don't have full classroom sets---it would be a waste of money.

@XanderHenderson But if you have enough properly secured enterprise laptops for the class, why would you want students to take tests on their own devices, which by definition can't be secured against cheating? It's an honor system with BYOD either way.

As I said above, my college does not maintain classroom sets of computers.  It doesn't make sense to keep several hundred machines around when they would likely only be used two or three times per year.  And yes, it is very much on the honor system; but I also think that a lot of instructors are overzealous about cheating, and overstate the effect that cheating has.  Like I said above, the majority of students who cheat are bad at it.
